# Including a predictor variable that is a proportion in panel regression

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, panel-data, proportion

I built a panel data model using the R `plm` package, and one of the predictor variables is a proportion. Should I perform any transformation on this variable as it is bounded by 0 and 1? Or is there another method of accounting for this proportion variable?

Comment: Is it a predictor (e.g. $x$) or the response (e.g. $y$)?

Comment: @Dave a predictor variable $x$. In fact, there are 2 variables in the data set that are a proportion of each other. So for example, $x_1=0.6$ and $x_2=0.4$.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate information by having $x_1 = p$ and $x_2 = 1-p?$ // To answer your explicit question, I would not do anything to the proportion. I would stick it in the regression like I would any other variable.

Comment: @Dave I'm only going to include one of these variables $x_1$. Thanks for the help, I'll leave it as is!